# Present perfect vs present perfect progressive

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, present-perfect, present-tense, perfect-continuous

> We have been living in Saudi Arabia ..
>
> We have lived in Saudi Arabia
>   ...

What is the difference between them, or they are the same in meaning ? 
And what do you understand, when you hear these two sentences?

Comment: Hi, Rema - Did you look up the [present perfect](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/) and the [present perfect continuous](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect-continuous/) (or progressive)?  What did you find, and was there something specific that you didn't understand?